# Why does "new Image()" trigger a network request at once but "createElement('script')" does not?

Tags: javascript, html

I use `new Image()` to create a new image element. When I set the 'src' attribute, a network request will be triggered at once. Why? Is there any documentation that explains it?

The following cases:

*Case 1*:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://someurl.png';
```

*Case 2*:

```
var imgStr = '<img src="http://someurl.png">';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = imgStr;
```

*Case 3*:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://someurl.js';
// document.body.appendChild(script);
```

In *case1* and *case2*, a network request will be triggered at once.

In *case3*, if I don't append the script element to the body, no network request will be triggered.

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure this will help, step 24 in [preparing script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#prepare-a-script), explains the `script` tag's `src` behavior, which the user agent(browser) has to follow:

> For performance reasons, user agents may start fetching the classic
>   script or module graph (as defined above) as soon as the src attribute
>   is set, instead, in the hope that the element will be inserted into
>   the document (and that the cross-origin attribute won't change the value in
>   the meantime).
>
> Either way, once the element is inserted into the
>   document, the load must have started as described in this step. **If the
>   UA performs such prefetching, but the element is never inserted in the
>   document or the src attribute is dynamically changed, or the
>   crossorigin attribute is dynamically changed, then the user agent will
>   not execute the script so obtained, and the fetching process will have
>   been effectively wasted.**

---

[This](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#when-to-obtain-images) explains how and when the image resource needs to be load even though the image element isn't in the DOM:

> A user agent that obtains images immediately must synchronously update
>   the image data of an img element, with the restart animation flag set
>   if so stated, whenever that element is created or has experienced
>   relevant mutations.
>
> **A user agent that obtains images on demand must update the image data
>   of an img element whenever it needs the image data (i.e., on demand),
>   but only if the img element's current request's state is unavailable.**
>   When an img element has experienced **relevant mutations**, if the user
>   agent only obtains images on demand, the img element's current
>   request's state must return to unavailable.

---

Further on `img` element's [DOM manipulation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#reacting-to-dom-mutations):

> The relevant mutations for an img element are as follows:
>
> - **The element's src, srcset, width, or sizes attributes are set, changed, or removed.**
> - **The element's src attribute is set to the same value as the previous value. This must set the restart animation flag for the update the image data algorithm.**
> - The element's `crossorigin` attribute's state is changed.
> - The element is inserted into or removed from a picture parent element.
> - The element's parent is a picture element and a source element is inserted as a previous sibling.
> - The element's parent is a picture element and a source element that was a previous sibling is removed.
> - The element's parent is a picture element and a source element that is a previous sibling has its `srcset`, sizes, media, or type attributes
>     set, changed, or removed.
> - The element's adopting steps are run.